# "err_ssl_protocol_error" when making requests to the backend

Tags: ssl, dns, frontend, backend, certbot

I have my dns server, with my domain and SSL certificate by certbot.

Everything works fine, but my problem is that when I try to request in my API, I have the problem "net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR", why did that happen?

My frontend and backend stayed on the same DNS, I use react and node.js.

My Firewall is not the problem, i opened the port that i use in my backend

When I try to browse any PORT opened from the server, I have the same problem

Comment: I use NGINX and Ubuntu 22.04 in my server.